# netCDF4 error HDF error when calling large data set?

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf

I'm running a code in python, which uses netCDF4. It's calling a data set of 65 GB on an external drive. When calling a section of this dataset (2 GB) from my laptop storage it doesn't have this error:

```
[Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error: b'/Volumes/external_drive/.../filename.nc
```

I'm pretty new to python, so help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean with _"When calling a section of.."_? Is that just reading in a 2GB chunk (variable?) from that file? Does it work with smaller NetCDF files, or if you read in a smaller chunk? And which library are you using (NetCDF4, xarray, ...)?

Comment: It works with small size files from my laptop, but because I don't have much space on my laptop I can't try large data sets from my laptop. When I try small data sets from the external drive I get the same error as above, so I presume it's more the external drive than the large data quantity.

Comment: That makes it a fairly difficult question to answer..... Googling for `HDF5 error 101` mostly results in issues related to write access, i.e. if you try to open the file with write access, and it is already opened with write access by someone else. Could that be an issue here? How are you opening the file?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.
Set this flag to FALSE:

```
os.environ['HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING']='FALSE'
```